# obtaining the true value of fitted two parameter gamma distribution for mle and moment estimation method

Tags: mathematical-statistics

i have a data set on length of stay in the hospital and it was fitted to two parameter gamma distribution. from the data, i was able to obtain the MLE estimates of alpha and beta and the moment estimates of alpha and beta. now i want to compare the two estimators i.e MLE and Moment estimator using the MSE but i do not know how to obtain the true values. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to compare the estimates:

Best way is comparing them mathematically. Example is the moment estimate and MLE of mean and variance. The conclusion is: They are the same for mean; different on variance by factor $n/(n-1)$ where $n$ is sample size.

Second way is simulation. You can generate the sample by computer according to specified true parameter values. Then apply the estimators to the data to get the estimate of the parameters. Repeat this process many times, say 10,000, then you can describe, evaluate, compare the estimators based on observed bias and mean square error.

For your situation, one sample with unknown parameter, it is impossible to compare the estimators.